# How to save the levels of a variable from Stata as an Excel file

Tags: stata

I am working with some data where a categorical variable has numerous (>1k) levels. I need to create an Excel sheet where each row is one of the levels. I understand how to use `levelsof(variable), clean` to view these levels, but do not understand how to export this using a command.

I tried saving it locally using `levelsof(variable), clean, local(levels)` and then using `putexcel` to make an Excel file, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that

```
levelsof(variable), clean, local(levels)
```

does not work, as there are too many commas (the second comma makes the command illegal). But with that fixed, it's still the wrong idea, because you need to undo all the work of `levelsof` and get a variable fit to be sent to Excel as a column. I have nothing against `levelsof`, which I first wrote.

Here is one way to do it.

In this example, there are no duplicates, but the `duplicates` command is needed for when there are. If you want to `export` a different kind of file, just choose a different `export` command.

```
sysuse auto, clear

capture frame drop levels
frame put make, into(levels)

frame levels {
duplicates drop make, force
export delimited using levels.csv
}
```